# Ignoring a subfolder on a git pull (but not on a git push)

Tags: git

In my git repository there is a subfolder `./foo`.

**Question:** Is it possible to ignore `foo` when running a `git pull`, but *not ignore* `foo` when running a `git push`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shord answer: no. Git unlike e.g. SVN doesn't operate with commits on folder level.

The long answer: since a given file tree is an undisposable part of a given commit, you can't pull a given commit w/o part of the commit.

But you can instead do as follows:

```
git fetch <remote>
git merge --no-commit <required remote branch>
[edit the changes of the merge as you need, use git checkout <revision> -- <path> etc..]
git commit
```

Or there're other possible ways to solve your problem :)